# How to get image data from Windows clipboard

Tags: image, go, clipboard

I am trying to write a program in Golang to get image data from Windows Clipboard.

I understand that [there is a plugin for getting data from Windows Clipboard](http://atotto/clipboard:%20clipboard%20for%20golang%20-%20GitHub), the problem is it does not support image data, text only. Basically just not what am I looking for.

```
package main

import ("fmt"
        "github.com/atotto/clipboard"
)


func main()  {
    str,err:=clipboard.ReadAll()
    if err!=nil {
        fmt.Println(err)        
    }else {
        fmt.Println(str)
    }
}
```

This will output the "The operation completed successfully." error if the clipboard contains an image.

Any idea how to do this?

**Update!:**

I tried passing `CF_BITMAP` to `GetClipboardData`, which return a handle to a bitmap (Hbitmap). I am not familiar with handling that, but apparently it is a long unsigned number?

Anyway, I tried some googling at came to [this](https://github.com/lxn/win/blob/master/gdiplus.go). Using the function `GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP`:

```
var Bitmap *win.GpBitmap
pBitmap := &Bitmap
fmt.Println(win.GdipCreateBitmapFromHBITMAP(win.HBITMAP(Hbitmap),0,pBitmap))
```

I got an "ok" output, but the Bitmap is empty. And I am stuck again.

How am I supposed to store the bitmap?

Comment: did you figured it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who still looking for a solution. Here is an active Go package that can deal with UTF8 and image clipboard data:

https://github.com/golang-design/clipboard

It is also cross-platform (Linux/Windows/macOS) without additional dependencies, which is a good replacement for the mentioned atotto/clipboard package.

Answer (score 4):

### The problem

The `github.com/atotto/clipboard` package appears to specifically target operating on text, and it's cross -platform, so that's what you get.

On Windows™, the package uses the standard Win32 API to access the clipboard.
Specifically, [this statement](https://github.com/atotto/clipboard/blob/579379fa8ff8a6d3fa979cec107f8f6d7f8fde90/clipboard_windows.go#L59) calls [`GetClipboardData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboarddata) passing it the [`CF_UNICODETEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-formats) format parameter, and that's why the operation completes successfully: it returns what text the clipboard contains (in your case—none, an empty string).

### The solution

The straightforward solution is to copy the relevant bits of the Windows-specific code from that package and modify the argument in the call to `GetClipboardData` to `CF_BITMAP` instead.

A more involved solution may be to first perform a series of calls to [`EnumClipboardFormats()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-enumclipboardformats) and figure out whether any image data (`CF_BITMAP`) is available, and call `GetClipboardData` only in the case it is.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but passing `CF_BITMAP` to `GetClipboardData` yield another problem which I have updated in my question. Can you have a look?

Comment: @CSDD, this turned out to be trickier to get right than I expected. I've got a half-working solution by now; hope to get it ready in several hours.